# A rather complicated auto increment

Tags: mysql

This is one idea more complicated than a one-to-many connection. I have a bunch of tables like photos, posts, users etc. that can be commented on. My comments table contains 3 fields that help identify the comment:

`item-id` - the id of the item the comment belongs to
`table` - the table which `item-id` resides in ( saved as an integer, but displayed as name below to avoid confusion )
`id` - the id of the comment, relative to the `item-id`

A sample for better understanding:

```
id  item-id table

1   1       photos
2   1       photos
1   1       posts
2   1       posts
1   2       posts
1   1       users
```

Now the problem is with inserts. I find it hard to determine the current last id. Given the table above if a user is to comment on a photo with `item-id` = 1, then the new comment needs to have an id of 3. The only way I could think of is to run a sub-query on insert but I'm not a big fan of sub-queries. Is there some mechanism built in mysql that can help me achieve this, or any other easy and robust way?

Comment: What's the advantage of using "natural looking" sequences like 1-2-3 for each parent instead of just relying on sequences as provided by the database server?  OK these will grow bigger, and they'll not be as neat as 1-2-3 but they're fast, robust and guaranteed to be collision-proof?

Comment: When I see table name as a column I want to run away from such architecture

Comment: This schema design is going to have race conditions in trying to determine that ID, and what happens if a post is deleted, the numbers are all decremented? My instinct is immediately that the schema design needs changing to meet the requirement in a different way, e.g. what is driving the need for this contiguous set of numbers, instead of using timestamps to providing ordering for comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MyISAM allows you to do this easily](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a
>   secondary column in a multiple-column index.

However, it's limited to two columns, so you still need to normalize this to remove one of the columns.

Otherwise, you can insert the next users (item 1) row like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, `item-id`, `table`)
SELECT MAX(id) + 1, 1, 'users' FROM table1 WHERE `item-id` = 1 AND `table` = 'users'
```

To extend it a little, the `IFNULL` part allows you to use the same clause for inserting the first row.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, `item-id`, `table`)
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0) + 1, 2, 'users' FROM table1 WHERE `item-id` = 2 AND `table` = 'users'
```

In this case, you would probably have a multi-column primary key, consisting of all three columns.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you should consider, why is this important to you? The purpose of an ID is to be a unique identifier. Sure it can represent order in the fact that it's monotonically increasing, but is there any reason it specifically has to go from 1 to 2 to 3 for each `(item-id, table)` pair? Would it be that harmful if it was instead 1, 6, 20?

If you're using PHP you'll still receive that data in the same order, and in PHP it'll be very easy to know which is 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I've come up with this because of the fear of unique ids running out. I know that the maximum integer value mysql can store is 1*10 to the 19th or something, which is a ridiculously large number, but not infinite. As well as numbers as huge take up more space? It's really a dilemma..

Comment: So just use the `insert . . . select` syntax.  It is much more flexible anyway.

Comment: Before you hit 10^19 entries, you will have a lot of other issues to resolve. A nominal 20 byte row of that quantity would be in the order of ~170 Exabytes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry I don't follow?

Comment: @php_nub_qq . . . The first sentence in this answer says "they aren't allowed in `INSERT table VALUES` statements.  Well, that is utterly irrelevant, because the syntax `INSERT INTO table SELECT` *does* support this capability.

Comment: @Andrew, that is a great point, but FWIW you're assuming you store a row for every value in the sequence. I've seen applications that skip values, or else the database keeps growing but prunes old data off the end. So one might need large id values for a smallish dataset.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment:

> I've come up with this because of the fear of unique ids running out. I know that the maximum integer value mysql can store is 1*10 to the 19th or something, which is a ridiculously large number, but not infinite. As well as numbers as huge take up more space?

MySQL's signed INT type can go up to 2<sup>31</sup>-1. An unsigned INT can go up to 2<sup>32</sup>-1, which is 4,294,967,295.

You're right this is not infinite, but 4.2 billion is pretty high and easily able to handle most needs.

You can also use a signed or unsigned BIGINT, which is 8 bytes, twice the size of an INT, but if you need values larger than INT, then you must store them.

Unsigned BIGINT goes up to 2<sup>64</sup>-1 or 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. You're really, really, really unlikely to exhaust these values in your lifetime, even if you re-load your entire database multiple times per hour.

---

Re your comment.

Yes, most data types are fixed-size, meaning they use the same number of bytes on every row, regardless of the value you store in it on any given row. The reason for this is that you could change the value later, and if MySQL had to find more space to grow a small numeric value into a large numeric value, it would lead to other kinds of performance problems.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html for more info on the number of bytes MySQL uses for each data type.

The exception is some string data types, (VARCHAR, VARBINARY, TEXT, BLOB), use a variable amount of space per row depending on the lengths of the strings you actually use.

But there are no *numeric* or *date/time* data types in MySQL that vary in size.

Another comment: you should ask yourself how much time & effort you're spending on optimizing this, and whether it would be more economical to just get a bigger disk. It's true the extra 4 bytes per row per integer adds up if you have a large database, but you'd need to store billions of rows before it really matters.

Comment: Just as a side question, if I were to define the column as BIGINT instead of INT, would there be more space preserved for numbers up until the INT limit? In other words will the number `5` saved as BIGINT take up more space than the same number saved as INT?